# Magento - Show Disabled products in collection

Tags: magento, collections

On my category page I am trying to show all it's products, even though they are all disabled.

On the category page I am using:

```
$categoryModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$_category_id  = $_category->getId();

$products = $categoryModel->load($_category_id)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect(array('id', 'name','etc...'))
->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
```

But my collection is always empty.

I have also tried using:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('status', 2)
```

Without success. If i switch the filter to enabled products with either:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)

->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
```

Then (in any other category where products are enabled) then the collection shows all products.

I have flat catalog turned off/set to No in my configuration and I am using community edition 1.9.0.0

Comment: the answer to your next question should be good also for this one.

Comment: What are your product visibilities set to? Is the status the only difference between a product you want to show and doesn't, and one that already shows?